# Data Filter with data-filter command

Tags: html

I'm creating some simple website with data-filter.

Here's how the part of the code looks:

`

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul id="portfolio-flters">
        <li data-filter=".filter-best, .filter-sport, .filter-esport, .filter-web" class="filter-active">All</li>
        <li data-filter=".filter-best">Best Casinos</li>
        <li data-filter=".filter-sport">Sport</li>
        <li data-filter=".filter-esport">E-Sport</li>
        <li data-filter=".filter-web">New</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="portfolio-wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-best filter-sport filter-esport filter-web"> <a href="x"> <img src="xx.jpg">
      <div class="details">
        <h4>TEST1</h4>
        <span>x</span> </div>
    </a> </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
      <a href="">
        <img src="xx.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="details">
          <h4>TEST2</h4>
          <span>Alored dono par</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>`
```

My question is, can I sort the list which is shown after choosing one of the options,
For example, when it's clicked on "NEW", I want the "TEST1" on second position and TEST2 on first position.

For now on the website it's shown in order how all records are provided in the code.

Thanks in advance, I'm learning everything so if you will need some more information from me, let me know.

Comment: HTML is plain markup. You need JS for that.

Comment: I have some JS in this web. I was using pre-template. Though I have no idea which one is for that and how I can change it or how sorting is described in there

Comment: Other question is if I can hide something while using HTML, for example, I will have an item in "NEW" section and I don't want to have it visible in "ALL". I'm tried different modifications, but for now nothing seems to be working.

Comment: As default all "items" are visible in tab "ALL", when I'm moving to other tab and getting to "ALL" there are only items selected. How to remove them from default, I'm struggling quite lot with it

Comment: I mixed the question a bit. What I'm trying to do is when I'm going to certain filter, how I can set manually the order how the objects are shown. At the moment all objects are visible in order how they are placed in HTML code. Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the JS part for it:

```
(function($) {

// Navigation scrolls
$('.navbar-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
$('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
var $anchor = $(this);
var nav = $($anchor.attr('href'));
if (nav.length) {
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 78
  }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

  event.preventDefault();
}
});

$(".navbar-collapse a").on('click', function() {
$(".navbar-collapse.collapse").removeClass('in');
});

// Porfolio filer
$("#portfolio-flters li").click(function() {
$("#portfolio-flters li").removeClass('filter-active');
$(this).addClass('filter-active');

var selectedFilter = $(this).data("filter");
$("#portfolio-wrapper").fadeTo(100, 0);

$(".portfolio-item").fadeOut().css('transform', 'scale(0)');

setTimeout(function() {
  $(selectedFilter).fadeIn(100).css('transform', 'scale(1)');
  $("#portfolio-wrapper").fadeTo(300, 1);
}, 300);
});

// Team Slider
$('.autoplay').slick({
dots: true,
infinite: false,
speed: 300,
slidesToShow: 2,
slidesToScroll: 3,
responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 3,
      infinite: true,
      dots: true
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2
    }
  },
  {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    }
  }
  
]
});

})(jQuery);`
```